# Pass video file

Tags: 7

I create a REST server with Drupal 7, set everything and it work correctly, node created well, but I want to fill File field with REST.

my client side code is the following.

```
(function($){
  function getCsrfToken(callback) {
  jQuery.get(('http://example.com//services/session/token'))
    .done(function (data) {
      var csrfToken = data;
      callback(csrfToken);
    });
}

function postNode(csrfToken, node) {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/rest/node',
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken
    },
    data: JSON.stringify(node),
    success: function (node) {
      console.log(node);
    }
  });
}

var newNode = {
  type:'video',
  title: 'Example node title3',
  body: {
    und: {
    0: {
    value :"Body"}
       }
    },
  field_url:{   
   und: {
     0: {
      value :"http://url.com"
    }
    }
    },
field_video:{
 ???????
 }
}; 

getCsrfToken(function (csrfToken) {
  postNode(csrfToken, newNode);
});
  })(jQuery);
```

How can I pass a file (or an image) to REST service? what should I write instead of `?????`?

Answer (score 1):

You could upload the file first using the file:create_raw services resource, which will return a file id (fid). Then you create your node and pass the fid in the file field {fid: "x}:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('files[file_1]', file);

jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://example.com/rest/file/create_raw',
    data: data,
    async: false,
    cache: false,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(result){
        alert(result);
    }
});
```

Comment: can you provide more details or an example or useful example link?

Comment: I have added some sample code

Comment: thanks, what is data, base64decode of file?

Comment: @zhilevan, no `data`'s type is [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) which provides a way to easily construct a set of key/value pairs representing form fields. `files[file_1]` is the key and `file` contains the raw file, either from HTML form file input , or a Blob, s. [Using FormData Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects)

Answer (score 0):

You will want to base64 encode the image file before you submit your document to the REST endpoint.

You an use https://www.base64encode.org/ to get an sample encoded image.

Comment: I know it is base64 file, but how to pass to Drupal REST( with which format)?
provide your answer according to my question please.